# how ref and out are different at run time?

Tags: c#, ref, out

in many of the articles they had given that `ref` and out `out` works in the same way.even at compile time recognises the both in same way but they are differed at run time(CLR).can anyone explain how it is differed? and functionality of out?

i tried the same in this code

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int par = 7;
        Program x= new Program();
        x.RefMethod(out par);
        Console.WriteLine(par);
        x.RefMethod1(ref par);
        Console.WriteLine(par);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public void RefMethod(out int i)
    {
        i = 10;

    }
    public void RefMethod1(ref int i)
    {
        i = 20;
    }
```

ILDASM for refmethod:

```
method public hidebysig instance void  RefMethod([out] int32& i) cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0004:  stind.i4
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::RefMethod
```

ILDASM for the Refmethod1:

```
method public hidebysig instance void  RefMethod1(int32& i) cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   20
  IL_0004:  stind.i4
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::RefMethod1
```

the above clearly shows that both are differed at one point i.e. at that method initialising.please can anyone help me out with my question?

Please any one answer the question with a clarity. I still aint got the answer :(

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to look at IL if you want to find out what happens at run time. To find the actual run time behavior, you need to look at the JIT compiled code. In this case there's no difference at run time. The constant value gets loaded into a register in both cases and `Console.WriteLine` is then called.

Comment: You say that "many articles" say that out and ref are different at runtime. Either those articles are wrong, or you are misunderstanding them. But it is difficult for us to criticize or explain articles that you haven't linked to!

Comment: @EricLippert: I menton this in [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329996/18192), but you may be interested to know that [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) states, "The in, ref, and out keywords cause different run-time behavior."

Comment: @Brian: Holy goodness, that is very misleading! Sadly I no longer know who is in charge of the C# documentation.

Comment: @Brian: I've entered this issue to try to get this and many other problems with this documentation resolved: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/10116

Comment: does ref and out are differed at symbol table?? @BrianRasmussen

Comment: @SAIguru011 I'm not sure I follow. A symbol table is typically a compiler construct but you're asking about run time behavior. Can you clarify please.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I am literally confused between these two keywords. I just need a clarity at which point of time they differ either at compile time or run time. and how? sorry for not giving the clarity in the question

Comment: @SAIguru011 at compile time they have different semantics as pointed out in the answers. See Eric's comment about run time behavior.

Comment: yes got some clarity on it!! thanks @BrianRasmussen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between ref and out is not in the CLR but in the C# language itself. Ref and Out differs in a way is that the "compiler requires different behaviour" for each of them. Method overloading also isnt allowed at compile time.

As you can see from the code, the only change is address reference specifically this line (if you put value 10, this will up as 10).

```
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   20
```

Comment: yes both ref and out has this ability but i want to know what is the actual difference between them and how out is treated at run time?

Comment: runtime no difference. only compile time.

Comment: Both ref and out are treated differently at run time and they are treated the same at compile time(this statement given in this article at difference between out and ref).  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/ref-vs-out-keywords-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer references misleading MSDN documentation, which has since [been corrected](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/11530).

---

[Gauravsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247650/18192) is correct. There is no run-time difference.

You mention https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/ref-vs-out-keywords-in-C-Sharp/, which states:

> Both ref and out are treated differently at run time and they are
>   treated the same at compile time, so methods cannot be overloaded if
>   one method takes an argument as ref and the other takes an argument as
>   an out.

The author of that article likely read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier , which states:

> Although the in, ref, and out keywords cause different run-time
>   behavior, they are not considered part of the method signature at
>   compile time. Therefore, methods cannot be overloaded if the only
>   difference is that one method takes a ref or in argument and the other
>   takes an out argument.

Personally, I agree with [jmoreno](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/272760/15162), who argues that the MSDN should have used the phrase, "require different behavior" instead of "cause difference behavior."

It's not surprising that you're seeing such an explanation in several places.  Probably many authors who try to use Microsoft's documentation as their primary source of information are providing the same misleading explanation.